# pythonで表を作成する便利な方法は？

Tags: python

pythonで表を図として出力したいと考えています。
CSVでの出力はできるのですが、行内での改行や列幅の操作も必要ですので、
後の編集の手間を考えると画像として表を作成したいです。
何か便利（楽）な方法はありませんでしょうか。

Comment: ＨＴＭＬとして出力してキャプチャするとか

Answer (score 5):

画像ではありませんが、端末に表を表示するなら[texttable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable)モジュールがあります。行内での改行や列幅の設定も可能です。

```
table = Texttable()
table.set_cols_align(["l", "r", "c"])
table.set_cols_valign(["t", "m", "b"])
table.add_rows([ ["Name", "Age", "Nickname"], 
                 ["Mr\nXavier\nHuon", 32, "Xav'"],
                 ["Mr\nBaptiste\nClement", 1, "Baby"] ])
print table.draw() + "\n"

table = Texttable()
table.set_deco(Texttable.HEADER)
table.set_cols_dtype(['t',  # text 
                      'f',  # float (decimal)
                      'e',  # float (exponent)
                      'i',  # integer
                      'a']) # automatic
table.set_cols_align(["l", "r", "r", "r", "l"])
table.add_rows([["text",    "float", "exp", "int", "auto"],
                ["abcd",    "67",    654,   89,    128.001],
                ["efghijk", 67.5434, .654,  89.6,  12800000000000000000000.00023],
                ["lmn",     5e-78,   5e-78, 89.4,  .000000000000128],
                ["opqrstu", .023,    5e+78, 92.,   12800000000000000000000]])
print table.draw()
```

Result:

```
+----------+-----+----------+
|   Name   | Age | Nickname |
+==========+=====+==========+
| Mr       |     |          |
| Xavier   |  32 |          |
| Huon     |     |   Xav'   |
+----------+-----+----------+
| Mr       |     |          |
| Baptiste |   1 |          |
| Clement  |     |   Baby   |
+----------+-----+----------+

text   float       exp      int     auto
===========================================
abcd   67.000   6.540e+02   89    128.001
efgh   67.543   6.540e-01   90    1.280e+22
ijkl   0.000    5.000e-78   89    0.000
mnop   0.023    5.000e+78   92    1.280e+22
```

Answer (score 2):

pandas.DataFrameを経由することでいくつかのフォーマットに出力しやすくなると思いますが、直接画像には出力できないようです。

[How to save the Pandas dataframe/series data as a figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726663/how-to-save-the-pandas-dataframe-series-data-as-a-figure)
でも述べられている通り、

- LaTeXで出力してpdflatex等で変換
- HTMLに変換してphantom.js等を用いて変換

としてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

以下のようにすれば `matplotlib` から画像として出力することはできます。
が、画像として出力すると 列幅などの調整はむしろ手間になるのではないでしょうか。

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.tools.plotting as plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
plotting.table(ax, df, loc='center')
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]